# How to list and get access to TabPage objects dynamically

Tags: c#, object, tabs, tabcontrol

I need to search my Form for a specific TabPage object with TabPages.Name property (or another way?) (i.e .Name == "Customer") and return the object so I can pass the object to a method.

I'm thinking there is some sort of class that has a method:

```
TabPage myTabPage = Objects.type.TabPage("Customer");
```

The tab was removed by a TabPages.Remove, and thusly is no longer connected to the TabControl
collection of TabPages but the object still exists. I want to use a TabPages.Insert to reconnect the **SAME instance** of the object to the collection and must pass the TabPage object to do so.

```
tabControl1.Tabpages.Insert(tabControl1.TabCount, myTabPage);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: _The tab was removed by a TabPages.Remove, and thusly is no longer connected to the TabControl collection of TabPages but the object still exists._ How do you know that? If there is no longer a handle to it it should be gone. You should create a handle to it before it gets removed.

Comment: Good question and saving a reference to the handle I was able to do.

Comment: To answer your question: after the "remove" , doing a Tabpages.IndexOfKey(myTabPage) returns -1. However, the insert adds the Tab back & I can see all of the controls(buttons, labels, text boxes) - same instance. When I do a straight TabPages.Add(myTabPage) none of the controls appear - different instance.  I can save the handles & name in an array and search through at a later time. I was going to have over 50 items and wanted to avoid If else statements. A clean and quick lookup would be slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access removed objects you need to keep references to them.

If you want to keep references to instances you create dynamically by a name you give them, you can use a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, TabPage> myPages = new Dictionary<string, TabPage>();
```

You can add them in any of these ways:

```
myPages.Add("Joe", tabControl1.TabPages[0]);
myPages.Add("Jill", tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage2"]);
myPages.Add("Jack", tabPage3);
```

Or you can use their Name property, if it is meaningful:

```
myPages.Add(tabPage1.Name, tabPage1);
```

And access them like this later:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myPages["Jill"]);
```

Just make sure that the Dictionary Keys are unique. This will cause a runtime error:

```
myPages.Add(tabPage1.Name, tabPage1);
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage());
myPages.Add(tabPage1.Name, tabPage1);
```

because the default Name is in the Dictionary already. You can use the Contains method to check on both the Keys and the Values:

```
if (!myPages.Keys.Contains(tabPage1.Name)) myPages.Add(tabPage1.Name, tabPage1);
if (!myPages.Values.Contains(tabPage1)) myPages.Add(tabPage1.Name, tabPage1);
```

Generic collections and especially `Dictionary<T,T>` are **wonderful**..

Warning 1: Using a different Key you still can add the same instance twice.

Warning 2: Since you are keeping those extra references, a page will not be destroyed and its memory released until the last reference is gone.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to C# and I didn't know of Dictionary. This is a big help and simplifies the coding effort.