# TabPage custom Tag object lifecycle

Tags: c#, .net

I am assigning a custom class with some information I need for each TabPage created:

```
MyClass custom = new MyClass();

TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
tabPage.Text = ...;
tabPage.Tag = custom;
tabPage.Controls.Add(...);
```

Unfortunately, the moment I click between tabs, or have a context menu and click something, the Tag object is lost.

From my understanding, you can set and use whatever you want inside Tag objects, so what's the issue?

I need this to be persistent until I want it to.

The issue still persists without explanation. I even tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590386/how-to-list-and-get-access-to-tabpage-objects-dynamically), with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was using a third party library that has setting "HotTrack" information as boolean (true/false) using the Tag property of the TabPages.

Removing this in the library (as I do not need it) allowed me to store my own information without getting lost or overriden.